# Programme that adds two number and print it?

Tags: python

Problem: Write a programme that can have **t lines** and in each line there are numbers "x" and "y". For input pc add them together and print the answer. (t is between 1 and 100)

EXAMPLE:

input:

```
1 2
3 4
```

output:

```
3
7
```

My problem is that i can write a code that gets two numbers from user and add them and print it. But i cant write a code that gets two numbers **in 100 lines (maximum)** and add them **all** two by two and print it.

Here is mine:

```
n = int(1)
for n in range(1, 100):
n1 = int(input("enter number 1: "))
n2 = int(input("enter number 2: "))
s = n1 + n2
print (s)
```

and if it is array, please help me with it. Im not good in array

Comment: process each line separately.

Comment: aamouie01 - So I'm clear... You can do this for only one tuple (`{1,2}`); but not 2 or more tuples (`{3.4}`)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Python2

It is not clear to me where you want to get your `t lines` of input.  If it is a file, then try:

```
with open('input') as f:
    for line in f:
        print sum(int(x) for x in line.split())
```

If you want to prompt the user for input:

```
while True:
    line = raw_input('Enter numbers: ')
    if not line:
        break
    print sum(int(x) for x in line.split())
```

#### Python3

If python3 is being used, then:

```
with open('input') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(sum(int(x) for x in line.split()))
```

and:

```
while True:
    line = input('Enter numbers: ')
    if not line:
        break
    print(sum(int(x) for x in line.split()))
```

Comment: while True:
    print sum(int(x) for x in raw_input().split())

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski That will not work. `raw_input` returns a `string` so that `for` loop would be iterating over individual characters.

Comment: But there is split after raw_input(). It works on python 2.7 just checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while True:
    line = input('Enter numbers: ')
    if not line:
        break
    print(sum(int(x) for x in line.split()))
```